# How to pass all received IDs through the function for in_category

Tags: plugins

There is a function that receives from the main category everything in its sub categories:

```
function get_cats(){
  $id       = 1;
  $tax  = 'category';
  $children = get_term_children( $id, $tax );

  foreach ( $children as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $tax );
    echo ''. $term->term_id .',';
  }
}
```

I need to pass all the received ID in the condition:

```
if ( in_category( array( get_cats() ) ) ) {
  //
}
```

Values are transmitted, but the entries themselves in these categories are not displayed, but only the id from the function
How to transfer them in in_category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass arrays by passing a string with commas into `array()`, that's not how arrays work in PHP. Your code is the equivalent of:

```
if ( in_category( array( '1,2,3,4' ) ) ) {
}
```

Which is checking for a single category with the ID `'1,2,3,4'`, which can't exist.

For what you want to do, your function needs to return an array of IDs, which will be passed directly into `in_category()`, without `array()`:

```
function get_cats(){
  $id       = 1;
  $tax      = 'category';
  $children = get_term_children( $id, $tax );
  $cats     = array(); // Prepare an array to return.

  foreach ( $children as $child ) {
    $term   = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $tax );
    $cats[] = $term->term_id; // Add ID to the array:
  }

  return $cats; // Return the array.
}
```

Then:

```
if ( in_category( get_cats() ) ) {
  //
}
```

However, it needs to be pointed out that your `get_cats()` function is extremely redundant. You're using `get_term_children()` to get the IDs of the children, but then for some reason you're looping through those IDs to get the full term, just so you can get the ID. This doesn't make sense, because you *already had the IDs*.

So really, you don't need the `get_cats()` function at all. Just use `get_term_children()`:

```
$term_ids = get_term_children( 1, 'category' );

if ( in_category( $term_ids ) ) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'm still just learning)))